# Replace foreach with linq

Tags: c#, linq

```
dt = ds.Tables[1];

foreach (EPSFromElement element in elementList)
{
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
            {
                var ColumnName = column.ColumnName;
                var ColumnData = row[column].ToString();
                var currentElement = Regex.Replace(element.Field_Label, @"\W", "");

                if (element.Module_Field_ID != null)
                {

                    if (currentElement == ColumnName)
                        element.ColumnValue = ColumnData;                                
                }
                else
                {
                    if (element.Field_Type_Name != "Checkbox")
                    {
                        if ("Q_" + element.Column_Name_ID == ColumnName)
                            element.ColumnValue = ColumnData;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if ("Q_" + element.Column_Name_ID + "_" + element.Value_Column_Name_ID == ColumnName)
                                    element.ColumnValue = ColumnData; 
                     }
                 }
        }
    }
}
```

I have a List of object(EPSElement). In EPSElement there is a field ColumnValue that gets data from a data table (dt = ds.Tables[1];). To achieve this i am using there foreach loop .Is there a better way to do this. I am not too happy with three for each loop. Can this be replaced by LINQ.

Comment: It looks like you are repeatedly replacing the value of `element.ColumnValue` with each row's data, is that intended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This translates reasonably well.  Each of the `foreach`-es translate into their own `from`, the few variables are each `let`s, and all of the `if`s end up being `where`'s.

```
var query = from element in elementList
            from row in dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
            from column in dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
            let ColumnName = column.ColumnName
            let ColumnData = row[column].ToString()
            let currentElement = Regex.Replace(element.Field_Label, @"\W", "")
            where (element.Module_Field_ID != null && currentElement == ColumnName)
            || (element.Field_Type_Name != "Checkbox" 
                    && "Q_" + element.Column_Name_ID == ColumnName
                || element.Field_Type_Name == "Checkbox"
                    && "Q_" + element.Column_Name_ID + "_" + element.Value_Column_Name_ID == ColumnName)
            select new { Element = element, ColumnData = ColumnData };

foreach (var item in query)
    item.Element.ColumnValue = item.ColumnData;
```

Note that since the logic in the `Where` is a bit complex, it may be best to refactor it out into it's own method in which you have something like:

```
where IsValid(element, ColumnName, currentElement)
```

The implementation can then be the logic in either my query or your original code, based on which you'd prefer.

Comment: It's *arguable* whether or not this is "better" (clarity, maintenance, etc.).

Comment: @Jason Certainly it's arguable, but by showing him how this would be implemented using LINQ he's now able to compare the two, and is able to make the judgement call as to whether or not he would prefer it or not.  If you haven't seen my edit, I most certainly would want to refactor out that checking into its own method.

Comment: @Servy: it's also worth mentioning that you could also simplify the select to `select new { Element, ColumnData }` (that is, the explicit declarations are unnecessary) if the first line is likewise changed to `from Element in elementList`. Whether that's better or not is a personal preference, but I think it helps make things even clearer.

Comment: @AndrewCoonce The main difference is that I'd personaly want a different naming convention; with pascal case for the anon object properties and camal case for the loop variables.  The decision not to do what you're describing was intentional.

Comment: Thanks guys. I really appreciate you guys giving me two options that i can choose from and immplement

Answer (score 5):

I would *never* attempt to replace that with LINQ. First, you're mutating inside the body of the `foreach` and that's a *bad* idea to attempt to do with LINQ. LINQ is about querying (the 'Q' in LIN **Q** is for **q** uery) and so shouldn't have side effects. But, even supposing that you were to replace the mutation with a projection to a new sequence of objects, converting that to LINQ would be *very* hard to read; too much nested logic. Leave it alone.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jason, I left this code as is for a while but having three foreach for some reason bugged me. Since leaving it as is a good idea was the validation I was looking for and now i can move forward with my coding without a nagging doubt

Comment: +1 Aside from the side effects I think I'd lose the will to live if I saw that in linq...

Comment: @Neha, if you really want just "clean up" the look move the inner most foreach loop to its own function called `void ProcessRow(EPSFromElement element, DataRow row)`. Highlight the block and `rt-click->Refactor->Extract Method` should be able to do it easily enough. If I have super deep nests I will do this sometimes my self to make it easier to read.

Comment: But the code in the OP *can* easily be translated into a query.  Throughout the whole thing, he only does one thing, and he does it to a filtered set of the given data.  Everything but the actual manipulation can be, fairly easily, translated into a query.

Comment: @Servy: I didn't say it *couldn't*. I do not think the LINQ query is clearer or easier to maintain than the procedural code the OP already has.